# Close window button 'x' Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small problem that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to execute e.g `my_exemplary_sound->stop()` before closing window with the red "x" button. I can't override `closeEvent()` because the window isn't "mainwindow". I create new window like this  :

```
QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView();
view->show();
```

Comment: provide a  [mre]

Comment: closeEvent() is defined in QWidget so you can still subclass QGraphicsView and implement your own closeEvent() method there.